# How to add json-ld to Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, json-ld

When trying to add a json-ld script tag to a section that gets teleported to the HEAD, the Vue 3 compiler fails with this error:

`VueCompilerError: Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates.`

Template:

```html
<template>
  <teleport to="head">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/",
        "potentialAction": {
          "@type": "SearchAction",
          "target": "https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
          "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
        }
      }
    </script>
  </teleport>
  <div>
    Hello world!
  </div>
</template>
```

How can I add this json-ld tag without installing additional dependencies?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A workaround is to use Vue's [built-in `component`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component) (i.e., `<component :is="'script'">`) instead of `<script>`:

```html
<template>
  <teleport to="head">
    <component :is="'script'" type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/",
        "potentialAction": {
          "@type": "SearchAction",
          "target": "https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
          "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
        }
      }
    </component>
  </teleport>
  <div>
    Hello world!
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-script-tags-in-vue-template-drl9c?file=/src/App.vue)

[image]